# Two Column Div Layout: Left = Fluid, Right = Fixed and Scrollable

Tags: css, html, layout

The layout for this is rather simple and easy to achieve and has been covered here a lot, my problem comes from when I want the right div to be scrollable.

I simply cannot get the left side to be fluid and statically positioned while allowing the right side to be a fixed width *and* scrollable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
    <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">   
    body {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #page-wrap {
        background: white;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #main-content {
        background-color: #797979;
        padding-right: 350px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #right-sidebar {
        background-color: #cacaca;
        width: 350px;
        float: right;
        overflow: auto;
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body> 
        <div class="page-wrap">         
            <div id="main-content">                 
                    <h2>Content Area</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="right-sidebar">
                Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>
            Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>
            Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>
            Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>Text<br/>

            </div>              
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set your html,body width and height to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/apaul34208/es2Bm/2/)

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #797979;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
#page-wrap {
    background: white;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#main-content {
    position:absolute;
    right:200px;
    left:0px;
    padding:20px;
}
#right-sidebar {
    background-color: #cacaca;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    right:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!

Looks like position: fixed was one of the things that was tripping me up

Comment: In your fiddle, #page-wrap should be .page-wrap, but it has no effect on the page either way, so really it can be safely removed.